# Insert Image as a shape in Visio - VBA

Tags: vba, visio

I want to be able to import an image as a shape in Visio using VBA. I've tried to insert an image using the following, but it doesn't work...
`myShape.Import(imagePath)`

However, `myPage.Import(imagePath)` works fine and places an image in the center of the page, but I have no way of manipulating it as a shape. I've tried searching the web, but can't seem to find a way to do this using VBA.

Comment: `Import()` returns a reference to the imported shape.  You can use that reference to manipulate the image. `Set shp = Import(imagePath)`

Comment: Hi Tim, there is no Import function though.

Comment: To clarify, Page.Import returns a shape you can manipulate.  One of those manipulations can be to add the new image shape to a group that acts as a frame around the image, for example.

Comment: @S. Multani - Docs say return value of the method is "Shape". Did you try it?    BTW there's no strict definition saying methods cannot return values. A function is also a method.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clearing that up. I was confused with the `Import(imagePath)` as it made it seem like there is a built-in function Import in the Visio library.

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to manipulate the image as a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on @tim and @mike comments here's a quick snippet that wraps the import part into a function

```
Sub TryAddImage()
Dim vPag As Visio.Page
Set vPag = ActivePage
Dim shpImg As Visio.Shape

Set shpImg = AddImageShape(vPag, "C:\MyImage.jpg")

If Not shpImg Is Nothing Then
    'Do something to your new shape
    shpImg.CellsU("Width").FormulaU = "=Height*0.5"
End If
End Sub


Private Function AddImageShape(ByRef vPag As Visio.Page, fileName As String) As Visio.Shape
Dim shpNew As Visio.Shape
If Not vPag Is Nothing Then
    Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
    UndoScopeID1 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Insert image shape")

    On Error Resume Next:
    Set shpNew = vPag.Import(fileName)

    If Not shpNew Is Nothing Then
        Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True
    Else
        Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, False
    End If
End If
Set AddImageShape = shpNew
End Function
```

Basically, the function tries to return a shape from the [import method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767737.aspx).  If the method creates an error, either by a non-existent path or from the appropriate image filter not being installed, then the function returns 'Nothing', and you can then test for this in your calling code.